# PostgreSQL - Get related columns of an aggregated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "places"

```
origin | destiny | distance
---------------------------
A      | X       | 5
A      | Y       | 8
B      | X       | 12
B      | Y       | 9
```

For each origin, I want to find out which is the closest destiny. In MySQL I could do

```
SELECT origin, destiny, MIN(distance) FROM places GROUP BY origin
```

And I could expect the following result

```
origin | destiny | distance
---------------------------
A      | X       | 5
B      | y       | 9
```

Unfortunately, this query is not working in PostgreSQL. Postgre is forcing me to either put "destiny" in his own aggregate function or to define it as another argument of the GROUP BY statement. Both "solutions" change completely my desired result.

How could I translate the above MySQL query to PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL is the only DBMS that allows the broken ("lose" in MySQL terms) group by handling. Every other DBMS (including Postgres) would reject your original statement.

In Postgres you can use the `distinct on` operator to achieve the same thing:

```
select distinct on (origin) 
       origin, 
       destiny, 
       distance
from places
order by origin, distance;
```

The ANSI solution would be something like this:

```
select p.origin, 
       p.destiny, 
       p.distance
from places p
  join (select p2.origin, min(p2.distance) as distance
        from places  p2
        group by origin
) t on t.origin = p.origin and t.distance = p.distance
order by origin;
```

Or without a join using window functions

```
select t.origin,
       t.destiny,
       t.distance
from (
    select origin, 
           destiny, 
           distance, 
           min(distance) over (partition by origin) as min_dist
    from places
) t 
where distance = min_dist
order by origin;
```

Or another solution with window functions:

```
select distinct origin,
       first_value(destiny) over (partition by origin order by distance) as destiny, 
       min(distance) over (partition by origin) as distance
from places
order by origin;
```

My guess is that the first one (Postgres specific) is probably the fastest one.

Here is an SQLFiddle for all three solutions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/68308/2

---

Note that the MySQL result might actually be incorrect as it will return an arbitrary (=random) value for destiny. The value returned by MySQL might not be the one that belongs to the lowest distance.

More details on the broken group by handling in MySQL can be found here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 2):

The neatest (in my opinion) way to do this in PostgreSQL is to use an aggregate function which clearly specifies *which* value of `destiny` should be selected.

The desired value can be described as "the first matching `destiny`, if you order the matching rows by their `distance`".

You therefore need two things:

- A ["first" aggregate](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_%28aggregate%29), which simply returns the "first" of a list of values. This is very easy to define, but is not included as standard.
- The ability to specify what order those matches come in (otherwise, like the MySQL "loose Group By", it will be undefined which value you actually get). This was added in PostgreSQL 9.0, and [the syntax is documented under "Aggregate Expressions"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Once the `first()` aggregate is defined (which you need do only once per database, while you're setting up your initial tables), you can then write:

```
Select
       origin, 
       first(destiny Order by distance Asc) as closest_destiny, 
       min(distance) as closest_destiny_distance
       -- Or, equivalently: first(distance Order by distance Asc) as closest_destiny_distance
from places
group by origin
order by origin;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d85cf/2) showing the whole thing in operation.

Comment: I like the simplicity of your approach. It seems more logical to me that the DISTINCT ON operator

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is using plain aggregates, not Window functions. Somewhat simpler syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another possible solution to a_horse_with_no_name answer - using windowed function `row_num`:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by origin order by distance) as row_num,
        *
    from places
)
select
    origin, 
    destiny, 
    distance    
from cte
where row_num = 1
```

It'll work in SQL Server or other RDBMS supporting `row_number` too. In PostgreSQL, though, I prefer `distinct on` syntax.

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/68308/4)

Comment: Nice one as well - that makes three different solutions using window functions now.